# Issues when inserting QLR file (created from an LYR file) into QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, layer-file, qlr

I hope someone can help. I have checked a similar question on this issue here: [Problem when inserting a QLR file in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198469/problem-when-inserting-a-qlr-file-in-qgis) However the fixes there either don't work for me or I am doing something wrong.

I started out with a .lyr file of global biomes downloaded from the WWF at https://www.worldwildlife.org/publications/terrestrial-ecoregions-of-the-world

I used SLYR community edition to convert the .lyr to a .qlr which I named biomes.qlr I created a new project in the same folder where I had stored the biomes.qlr.

Now, when I load the biomes.qlr into the new project I get the error "Unavailable layer, data source cannot be found"

I go to 'repair data source' and select the correct data source, but this does not fix the issue. When another user had this issue (link to the question above), they found when examing the .qlr file that the data source was the original (online) data, they changed it to an absolute, rather than relative, path and the problem was fixed.

So I look at the .qlr file in notepad and see that the datasource is indeed the original data source. I changed the file in ntepad so the datasource is now my root directory where I have the qlr file stored. However, when I load the revised qlr file, I get the same error and when I re-open the .qlr file in notepad, I see that the data source has changed itself back to the original online source, i.e; my edits have been erased!.

Any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: I always preferred using qml files and applying them to the source layer wherever it is located.  For a qlr you might see if getting away from the "originals" works for whatever reason.  So when you first get a layer as you like, export a new data file to your desired folder, add it and apply the symbology, then export the qlr for it.